# Higher surge rate with lower battery

Tags: uber-api

I read online that your surge algorithm will charge a higher rate to phones with a lower battery percentage. Is this true?

Also - could you please show me where in the API (feel free to paste) where the battery is monitored?

Thanks!

DB

Comment: "_your surge algorithm_" This isn't the Uber website...

Answer (score 1):

> I read online that your surge algorithm will charge a higher rate to phones with a lower battery percentage. Is this true?

No. This is not true. I believe you are conflating this idea with a study that shows users will be more likely to accept / decide to take a surge price Uber if their batteries are lower. Uber definitely does not charge you a higher rate or give you a higher surge if your battery is low.